# How to get term meta WPGraphQL/WooGraphQL?

Tags: wordpress, wp-graphql

I'm using Woo GraphQL and I'm wondering how I should go about getting the color of product attributes. See below for a screenshot of the product attribute in WP Admin:

[image]

I've tried querying for the top-level `pa-` attribute and I've tried querying in `terms`/`termNode` with no luck.

Am I missing something? How do I get this data?

---

Update: So TIL, that colors in products attributes were actually provided via "Variation Swatches for WooCommerce". Variation Swatches takes this info and saves it in term meta.

So now my question is a bit different: How do I pull term meta?

Comment: See docs, its is as simple as querying any normal taxonomy, make sure to pass the correct terms & taxonomy ids in your query : [Querying Custom Taxonomies](https://docs.wpgraphql.com/getting-started/custom-taxonomies/#querying-custom-taxonomies)

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I have found is to not use (or with addition to ) WooSwatches plugin us should use [advanced custom fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and [WPGraphQL for Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.wpgraphql.com/acf/) in the following way

- add a new field groupe with name **Color Hex** that has the location rule `Taxonomy` is equal to `Color` (or what ever attribute you want to use)

[image]

- add a field with the name hex (for example) with type of color picker and make show in graphql

[image]

- you should be able to query the data like this

```
paColors {
  nodes {
    id
    name
    description
    colorHex {
      hex
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is also how i am doing it, but there should be a better way right? Did you find a better way in the mean while?

Comment: in fact this also gives me the option to pull the hex code and use it in the front end, so i prefer to use this way but there should be a better way if you only need the meta

Answer (score 0):

You can get term meta using the `get_term_meta()` function. See more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/).

I believe the meta key you want for this `swatch_id`.